# ASP.NET MVC - Where is HttpContext.Current stored?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm storing a lot of sensitive information in it.  Is it something that can be seen by end-user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot. It's fine to store sensitive information there. In fact - it's where .net membership creates the User object for authentication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650037.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually no. The session informations are in your server. 
Hidden html objects (including view state), cookies or your querystring can be seen by end - user